# Evitar que al reemplazar una ruta de imagen en la bd sea eliminada la imagen de las carpetas en php

Tags: php

Estoy intentado crear un crud con php, pero me encuentro en la parte de editar con algunas dudas en especifico con la parte de actualizar imágenes, estoy trabajando las imágenes con rutas, es decir que me almacena la imagen en una carpeta del sistema y la ruta es insertada en la bd, pero estoy enfrentándome con una cuestión en particular, en una de las carpetas del sistema tengo una imagen predeterminada que es colocada cuando un usuario es creado y no se coloca una foto propia, la cuestión es que no tengo idea de como evitar que, cuando se va a actualizar la foto de usuario por una propia si tiene asignada la imagen predeterminada al ser sustituida por una nueva no me elimine en especifico esa foto predeterminada, ya que es utilizada por otros.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['txtnombre']) && !empty($_POST['txtcorreo'])){
require '../global/sesiones.php';
require '../global/cn.php';

$id = $_POST['txtid'];
$nombre= filter_var($_POST['txtnombre']);
$matricula= filter_var($_POST['txtmatricula']);
$correo= filter_var($_POST['txtcorreo']);
$grado= filter_var($_POST['txtgrado']);
$grupo= filter_var($_POST['txtgrupo']);
$ciclo= filter_var($_POST['txtciclo']);
$nivel= filter_var($_POST['txtnivel']);
$tutor1= filter_var($_POST['txttutor1']);
$tutor2= filter_var($_POST['txttutor2']);
$tutor3= filter_var($_POST['txttutor3']);

$consulta2 = $mysqli->prepare ("SELECT foto FROM alm WHERE matricula = '$matricula' ");
$consulta2->execute();
$resultado2 = $consulta2->get_result();
$row = $resultado2->fetch_assoc();

$extension = '';
$ruta ='images/alumnos';
$archivo = $_FILES['txtfoto']['tmp_name'];
$nombre_archivo = $_FILES['txtfoto']['name'];
$info = pathinfo($nombre_archivo);

if ($archivo != ''){

$extension=$info['extension'];
if ($extension == "jpg" || $extension== "JPG" || $extension== "PNG" || $extension =="png" || $extension == 'JPEG' || $extension == 'jpeg'){

    if(
        // Se obtuvo un resultado de la consulta
        isset($row['foto'])
        // Y hay una imagen previa
        && $row['foto'] != ''
        // Y no es la predeterminada, solo ajusta ruta y nombre
        && $row['foto'] != $ruta . '/images/default/sinfoto.png'
    ){
        if(file_exists('../'.$row['foto'])){
            unlink('../'.$row['foto']);
        }
    }


    move_uploaded_file($archivo,'../images/alumnos/'.$nombre_archivo);
    $ruta = $ruta."/".$nombre_archivo;

}else{
    header('location:../extend/alerta.php?msj=el formato no es valido&c=us&p=in&t=error');
    exit;
}
$consulta1= $mysqli->prepare ("UPDATE alm SET foto = '$ruta' WHERE matricula = '$matricula' ");
$resultado1 = $consulta1->get_result();
$consulta1->execute();
}

$consulta = $mysqli->prepare ("UPDATE alm SET nombre = '$nombre', matricula = '$matricula', correo = '$correo',grado = '$grado',grupo = '$grupo',ciclo = '$ciclo', nivel = '$nivel' WHERE matricula = '$matricula' ");
$resultado = $consulta->get_result();
$consulta3 = $mysqli->prepare ("UPDATE papas SET matricula = '$matricula', nombre1 = '$tutor1', nombre2 = '$tutor2', nombre3 = '$tutor3' WHERE matricula = '$matricula'");
$resultado3 = $consulta3->get_result();

if($consulta->execute()){
$consulta3->execute();
echo'<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Registro modificado");
window.location.href="../vistapanel.php";
</script>';
$mysqli->close();
}else{
echo'<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Error al modificar los datos, revisarlos nuevamente");
window.location.href="../vistapanel.php";
</script>';
}

}else{
echo'<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Por favor introducir todos los campos");
    window.location.href="../vistaeditarcredencial.php";
    </script>';
}
?>
```

Como tal el código funciona para actualizar la ruta en la bd y reemplazar la foto de la carpeta en la que se encuentre solo que no tengo idea de como hacer esa condición para que si tiene la imagen predeterminada no me la elimine.

Comment: Explica mejor tu problema. ¿A qué te refieres por *imagen predeterminada* y en qué contexto (base de datos, documento html, etc)? ¿En qué parte de tu código intentas resolver tu problema y qué resultados obtienes?

Comment: No es tan complicado: Al crear el usuario, deja la imagen en blanco. Cuando muestres los datos, si no tiene imagen asignada, muestras la predeterminada del sistema. Si tienes duda, por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código que usas para mostrar imagen del usuario en otras secciones del sitio.

Comment: No necesariamente tienes que eliminar la foto. Tengo un sistema parecido y lo que hago es cada vez que se sube una foto se le nombra *usuario_001.jpg*, *usuario_002.jpg*, etc... y se guardan en un almacén físico. Desde un formulario se asigna (y se actualiza en la BD) cuál de todas las imágenes disponibles es la que se va a mostrar. Así mantengo un historial de fotos, pero si quieres, desde ahí también la podrías poner un botón para eliminar cualquiera de las imágenes, pero a nivel de archivo.

Comment: ¿Cuál es exactamente la ruta de la imagen `sinfoto.png`?

Comment: @Triby la ruta seria esta se ubica en la carpeta de imágenes y dentro de ella una subcarpeta default donde alberga la foto predeterminada : images/default/sinfoto.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una de las cosas que podrías hacer para no modificar el resto del sistema, es verificar que no se esté usando la imagen predeterminada, que, como dices en comentarios, está en `images/default/sinfoto.png`:

```
$extension=$info['extension'];
if ($extension == "jpg" || $extension== "JPG" || $extension== "PNG" || $extension =="png" ){

    if(
        // Se obtuvo un resultado de la consulta
        isset($row['foto'])
        // Y hay una imagen previa
        && $row['foto'] != ''
        // Y no es la predeterminada, solo ajusta ruta y nombre
        && $row['foto'] != 'images/default/sinfoto.png';
    ){
        if(file_exists('../'.$row['foto'])){
            unlink('../'.$row['foto']);
        }
    }

    move_uploaded_file($archivo,'../images/alumnos/'.$nombre_archivo);
    $ruta = $ruta."/".$nombre_archivo;

}else{
    header('location:../extend/alerta.php?msj=el formato no es valido&c=us&p=in&t=error');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Listo colega intente modificando esa parte de código sin embargo no me funciono sigo averiguando para hacerlo de esa forma, gracias colega!

Comment: @GustavoCuevasPalafox, por favor edita la pregunta para poner tu código actualizado, junto con datos adicionales de la imagen predeterminada (ruta, nombre, etc.). Por cierto, edité la respuesta.

Comment: listo coloque mi código para editar los datos, funciona completamente, solo que no logro que me deje de eliminar la foto predeterminada

Comment: Triby te ha preguntado cual es la ruta de tu foto predeterminada en los comentarios de la pregunta, por si no lo has visto, porque seguramente ve que lo que pones aqui: `$ruta . '/images/default/sinfoto.png'` no se corresponde con la ubicación correcta de dicha imagen (mas bien te creara esta ruta:  `images/alumnos/images/default/sinfoto.png` que pinta incorrecta).

Comment: @GustavoCuevasPalafox, actualicé la respuesta, solo asegúrate de usar la ruta correcta, podrías verificarla desde PhpMyAdmin para saber cuál es.

Comment: @Triby amigo en efecto así ya no me elimino la foto! Agradecido con tu ayuda